# Picklist deactivate link

Tags: picklist

I want to know the answer. I created a picklist. That picklist values has Deactivate link. When that Link will be appear?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a setup action that will Deactivate the Picklist Option(Remove the option from the picklist for users)). It (deactivate) will never be presented to the users.

Comment: How to remove that link?

Comment: @JanaShree you can't.  unless you somehow go back to an older version of the Salesforce platform.  It was just introduced recently (maybe Summer '16?)